# Issue uploading images

Tags: images

I never had issues with images, but now all of sudden newly uploaded images show the broken image icon and when I proceed inserting it I see the broken image in the post.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

**Issue details:**

1) The images on the front-end doesn't show as inline images, they only show up as attachments.
2) The issue persists only on the main site, images on all subsites work fine

**I tried to resolve the issue by doing following things with no success:**

1) switched back to the default theme.
2) disabled all plugins to see if
3) it's a conflict issue tried to reset permalinks

Could anybody help?

P.S.- It's a local setup and a multisite installation which I have been running for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Are your Wordpress URL and Site Address URL the same?

I had a similar issue whereby one had a backslash and the other didn't which caused it. Also, could you try inspecting the element in Chrome or Firefox and seeing where the URL points? Can you get to this URL directly from the browser?

Comment: Yes! I doubt it is the path issue.

By the way, there is nothing like Site Address and WordPress URL. It is just one multisite installation.

Comment: Can you get to the file directly, without loading it in an image tag or do you get a 404? Does the path in the img tag match where the file has actually uploaded?